# Why does a ternary operator make a character variable print an integer rather than a character?

Tags: java, integer, character, conditional-operator

```
char g = 'G';
int i = 0;
System.out.print(1 == 1 ? g : 0);
System.out.print(" ");
System.out.print(1 == 0 ? i : g);
```

In theory, this should print out "G G" as it prints the value of the character variable both times.
However, the second time it prints out the ASCII value of the character 'G'.

The code above will print out "G 71" which is not what is expected.

```
char g = 'G';
int i = 0;
System.out.print(1 == 1 ? g : 0);
System.out.print(" ");
System.out.print(1 == 0 ? 0 : g);
```

However, the second bit of code will print out "G G" which is what is expected.

Answer (score 5):

Because the ternary `? :` operator is still a single expression, which must still have a single type, because Java is statically typed. As a result, the types must match or be made to match. If the types cannot be made to match, an error results. However, a `char` can be implicitly converted to an `int` but not vice versa, so that is exactly what happens, as per the integer promotion rules.

The reason why `System.out.print(1 == 0 ? i : g);` causes the implicit conversion but not `System.out.print(1 == 0 ? 0 : g);` is because 0 is a **constant expression** already representable as a `char` but `i` is not, because `i` is a variable of type `int`.

From the [Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

> The type of a conditional expression is determined as follows:
>
> ...
>
> - If one of the operands is of type T where T is byte, short, or char, and the other operand is a constant expression (§15.28) of type int whose value is representable in type T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.
>
> ...
>
> - Otherwise, binary numeric promotion ([§5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)) is applied to the operand types, and the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the second and third operands.

Comment: In other words: with an (int) constant fitting the range of the char, the resulting type is converted to char, and with a int variable (unrestricted to char) the resulting type is widened to int. Nice citing of the longer specification.

Comment: Another case is if the expression is **constant** but **does not fit in `char`** as in `System.out.print(1 == 0 ? -1 : g);` In this case `G 71` is printed because the expression has to be widened to `int` anyway to hold `-1`.